# Adding missing end_of_months values by different variables in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have the following xlsx file df.xlsx which [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b22SS.png):

```
client id    dax           dpd 
1            2000-05-30    7
1            2000-12-31    6
2            2003-05-21    6 
3            1999-12-30    5
3            2000-10-30    6
3            2001-12-30    5
4            1999-12-30    5
4            2002-05-30    6
```

It's about a loan migration from a snapshot to another. The problem is that I don't have all the months in between. (ie: client_id = 1 , dax is from 2000-05-30 and 2000-12-30) . I have tried several approaches but no result. I need to populate by client_id all the months in between dax and keep the same "dpd" as the first month. (ie client_id = 1 , dax is from 2000-05-30 and 2000-12-30, dpd=7 for all months except the last one "2000-12-31" where dpd= 6). If the client_id appears only once (like client_id = 2 ) it should remain the same. 
(dpd means days past due aka rating bucket) 
I have tried this code:

```
df2 <- data.frame(dax=seq(min(df$dax), max(df$dax), by="month"))

df3 <- merge(x=df2a, y=df, by="dax", all.x=T)
idx <- which(is.na(df3$values))
for (client_id in idx) 
  df3$values[client_id] <- df3$values[client_id-1]
df3
```

but the results were not quite okay for what i need. 
i appreciate any advice. thank you very much!

Comment: It helps to make your question reproducable. Any variables your code refers to should be created in your question so that others can run your code and help you faster. So in your case, you should include code that creates your dataframes `df` and `df2a` (or creates sample dataframes with the same structure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to generate seqence of dates, given the start/end date.

R code to do this would be (insert values from your dataframe):

```
seq(as.Date("2017-01-30"), as.Date("2017-12-30"), "month")
```

Edit after comment:

In this case you can split your data by clients first and then generate the sequences:

```
new_data <- data.frame()
customerslist <- split(YOURDATA, YOURDATA$id)
for(i in 1:length(customerslist)){
  dates <- seq(min(as.Date(customerslist[[i]]$dax)), max(as.Date(customerslist[[i]]$dax)), "month")
  id <- rep(customerslist[[i]]$id[1], length(dates))
  dpd <- rep(customerslist[[i]]$dpd[1], length(dates))
  add <- cbind(id, as.character(dates), dpd)
  new_data <- rbind(new_data, add)
}
new_data$V2 <- as.Date(new_data$V2)
```

Comment: thank you very much! yes, i want to generate the missing months. example: client_id = 1 and has allocated two dates in dax:  2000-05-30 and 2000-12-30 . and i want to generate the missing months between this two dates with the same client_id.